# How can I make child constructor if parent doesn't have constructor without params

Tags: c++, oop, c++14

I have library which I can't modify with parent class:

```
class A {
public:
   A(immpl i) { /* do smth */ }
}
```

I want to write child-class:

```
class B : public A { 
public:
    B(FSImplPtr impl) : A(impl) {};
};
```

All works fine. So I can create child-class by:

```
B(SomeFunction(new VFSImpl()));
```

So, I want to make constructor without params, like that:

```
 class B : public A { 
 public:
    B() : A(SomeFunction(new VFSImpl())) {};
 };
```

But when I tried it - I have an errors:

```
error: expected primary-expression before '(' token

  B() : A(FSImplPtr(new VFSImpl())) {}
                   ^

error: expected type-specifier before 'VFSImpl'
  B() : A(FSImplPtr(new VFSImpl())) {}
                    ^
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: For one, show us the real code as part of a proper [mcve]. In your "source" you have `B() : A(SomeFunction(new VFSImpl())) {};`, but in the error message you have `B() : A(FSImplPtr(new VFSImpl())) {}`. In your code `SomeFunction` is a *function* (if the name isn't lying). `FSImplPtr` is a *type*.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry. SomeFunction is a constructor of class FSImplPtr. You can read more about this class here: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/cores/esp8266/FS.h

Comment: I replace FSImplPtr in code on stuckoverflow because FSImplPtr is harder to understand what is it

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and show a [mre] that everyone else in the world can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, into a blank file, then reproduce your ***exact*** compilation error? There could be many reasons for the compilation error, C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. Without a [mre] it is unlikely that anyone can help you. See [ask] questions for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does VFSImpl exists? I didn't see it in the git-file. I think it is a typos and you need FSImpl.